# Removing popular answer if potentially a duplicate

Tags: discussion, answering-questions

Hi,
 I'm fairly new to SF and have used the site mostly to get answers for my questions and provide answers to questions I know (read: the basic point of the site).

I recently posted an answer on this question:
[In tail -f, how do I filter out stuff that has certain keywords?](https://serverfault.com/questions/270756/in-tail-f-how-do-i-filter-out-stuff-that-has-certain-keywords/270760#270760)

I answered at approximately the same time as another poster (he used egrep, and I used grep -E) and I will admit his came in first. I left mine because:

a) I was ignorant of the fact that egrep is just a symlink of 'grep -E' (hell, didn't even know egrep existed, tbh)

b) given A, I didn't realize mine was a duplicate answer.

My question is, from the perspective of helping the site (not my rep, since that's unimportant) do I just delete the answer and add a comment to his answer just because it came in first, regardless that it seems to be the popular choice?

Comment: `/bin/egrep` being a link to `/bin/grep` is distro dependent. On CentOS 5 it's a link on Ubuntu 9 & 10 it's separate binaries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> a) I was ignorant of the fact that egrep is just a symlink of 'grep -E' (hell, didn't even know egrep existed, tbh)

Well i'd say leave your answer ESPECIALLY since given 100 distro's `grep -E` is more likly to be available on all of them than the symlink `egrep` :) so you are adding value.

> b) given A, I didn't realize mine was a duplicate answer.

Meh happens all the time, alternate solutions are good, even if is is just syntactically different.

Answer (score 4):

You can delete the answer if you'd like, but it's not really necessary. Duplicate/synchronous answers happen all the time.

Answer (score 3):

I would say leave it, whether it's the most upvoted or not. Similar (duplicate) answers are a feature of the way the site works.

Answer (score 2):

You're welcome to leave your answer. If it offends the purpose of the site, we'll *let you know*.

Technically your answer is 'more portable' and would be ever so slightly 'more correct' (if such an idea exists) as I see it. I'd probably just upvote both correct answers in the sort of case..

Answer (score 1):

Leave it, for the reasons already mentioned. You posted a good answer, as clearly shown by the upvotes it has received.

When I see multiple answers with essentially the same information posted within a few minutes of each other I figure they were most likely being entered at the same time, each in good faith, and treat each according to its own merits. In such a case I don't discriminate against either just because there appears to be duplicated content. This is *very* different to someone posting the same information hours, days or even months after it has already been posted.